# Prove that the sum of the coefficients of the polynomial $f(x)$ is equal to $f(1)$.

Tags: polynomials

If I understood correctly, then I must assign to make it so that $f (x) = f (1)$. But the question arises. How ? Should I simply substitute the value $(1)$ into the place $(x)$ for a general polynomial formula of any degree? Or is there another option?

$f(x)= a_0x^n +a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+...+a_{n-2}x^2 +a_{n-1}x+a_n$

$f(1)=a_01^n +a_11^{n-1}+a_21^{n-2}+...+a_{n-2}1^2 +a_{n-1}1+a_n$

It seems to me that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track.   Just simplify further.  What is $1^n$?

Comment: Really ? It.s true ?

Comment: How can it be wrong when you can see it is right?

Comment: Well, the point is that I do not know their topic polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)= a_0x^n +a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+...+a_{n-2}x^2 +a_{n-1}x+a_n$

then $f(1)=a_01^n +a_11^{n-1}+a_21^{n-2}+...+a_{n-2}1^2 +a_{n-1}1+a_n$.

But $1^n=1^{n-1}=1^{n-2}=...=1^2=1$ so

$f(1)=a_0 +a_1+a_2+...+a_{n-2} +a_{n-1}+a_n$

i.e., a polynomial evaluated at $1$ is the sum of its coefficients.

Comment: Exercise:  What is $f(0)$?

Comment: @JWTanner Your comment is in fact the OP's previous question.

Comment: $f(0)=a_00^n +a_10^{n-1}+a_20^{n-2}+...+a_{n-2}0^2 +a_{n-1}0+a_n = a_n$ That if the sum of the coefficients of the polynomial was equal to $0$?

Comment: @SaintHentai If this is meant to be an exercise on *induction* (like some of your recent questions) then you'll need to give a *rigorous* proof by induction (e.g. by induction on the degree). The level of rigor expected depends on your (unstated)  context, but beware that arguments using ellipses ("...") are usually not considered to be rigorous inductive proofs.

Comment: @SaintHentai:  You are correct that $f(0)=a_n;$ at the time I wrote the exercise, I didn't realize it was your previous question